# Передать в gulp dest путь от корня системы

Tags: node.js, gulp

Я использую gulp и мне нужно каким-то образом передавать в `gulp.dest` путь из корневой папки не проекта, а системы.

Я знаю, что можно пользоваться конструкцией типа `../../`, но это не подходит потому что при перемещении папки с проектом в другое место все сломается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корень (в случае Windows - корень текущего диска) обозначается слешом: `/smth/abc`.

В случае Windows путь с буквой диска должен считаться абсолютным, но если нет, можно попробовать перед ним тоже поставить слеш или три слеша.

Comment: Ну есть ведь не только Windows. Я сейчас подумал, что не уверен, что gulp.dest сможет такой путь обработать. Вероятно надо брать абсолютный путь в системе и превращать его в относительный от проекта. Но я не уверен :-(

Comment: @dmitryshishkin, а что ему помешает обработать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [`path.relative`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to)

```
var relativePath = path.relative(process.cwd(), someFilePath);
```

Comment: Ответ нашел на английском Stack Overflow, но не получается закрыть вопрос сославшись туда, поэтому продублировал ответ здесь. Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696334/node-js-get-relative-to-project-src-path-of-file